# Avoid collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Oxide.Core.Libraries.Covalence;
namespace Oxide.Plugins
{
    [Info("AutoNoClip", "Test", "1.0.20")]

    class AutoNoClip : RustPlugin
    {
        void OnUserConnected(IPlayer player)
        {
        player.Command("noclip");
        player.Command("menu");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first plugin for the Rust video game and I'm getting this error in console

Comment: Sorry John, it suggested the tag so I misclicked

Comment: Does this code by itself actually demonstrate the issue? I don't see how you're getting that error from this code.

Comment: It's highly recommended that you provide the code where the collection is changed causing the exception.  None of the code provided modifies a collection so it's not possible to solve your problem.

Comment: I think it's a duplication of a foreach statement. I think I've stupidly posted this question when it's not the cause. It's in another plugin